# Why is REMOTE_ADDR only sometimes available as an Apache environment variable?

Tags: apache-2.2

To avoid having to parse `X-Forwarded-For` in Varnish, I'm trying to just set a header on the SSL terminator (currently Apache) that stores the direct client IP in a header.

On our development machine, this works:

```
RequestHeader set X-Foo %{REMOTE_ADDR}e
```

However, in staging it doesn't.  Specifically, the header is empty, as illustrated by both `varnishlog`:

```
13 TxHeader     b X-Foo: (null)
```

(On the development machine, this shows the IP address as expected.)

Similarly, logging `REMOTE_ADDR` shows that it only appears to be populated on the dev machine:

```
# Config
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %{REMOTE_ADDR}e" combined
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log" combined

# Log file, staging
<my ip> -

# Log file, development
<my ip> <my ip>
```

Since the dev machine is, well, a dev machine, it is different in a number of ways; however, I can't track down which difference is causing this.  The versions of Apache are the same (2.2.22), and I don't see anything relevant in any of the standard config files or `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`.  And the rest of the system is reasonably similar, since they're built off the same CentOS 5 base image.

I can't even tell from the Apache documentation whether `REMOTE_ADDR` is expected to exist or not as [an environment variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html), but it clearly works on one machine, whether by fluke or design, and the inconsistency is driving me mad.

Comment: Browser dependent behavior?  Underlying http client implementation?

Comment: hmmm not sure but can you check if `mod_setenvif` is enabled on both servers ?

Comment: Using the same clients (Chrome and httpie) to check.  The `setenvif_module` is statically compiled in, as reported by `httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES`.

Comment: what about mod_headers? Are you certain that REMOTE_ADDR is empty, that shouldn't be a case, it's more probable that headers are not set correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the sources, `REMOTE_ADDR` is set only for these handlers that come with the server itself: mod_proxy_scgi, mod_ext_filter, mod_include, mod_isapi, mod_cgid, and mod_cgi (only they call `ap_add_common_vars`) so somehow one of these handlers is getting called before mod_headers or mod_log_config on your dev box but not on the staging box. (You may have other handlers.)

In less technical speak, from the doc you reference it says the same thing:

> In addition to all environment variables set within the Apache
>   configuration and passed from the shell, **CGI scripts and SSI pages** (emphasis mine) are
>   provided with a set of environment variables containing
>   meta-information about the request as required by the CGI
>   specification.

Comment: Ah, I see; thanks.  I dug a bit more into it, but when I found myself writing an Apache module solely for the purpose of calling `ap_add_common_vars`, I took a step back and decided I was better off just parsing `X-Forwarded-For` in Varnish.

Answer (score 2):

If you use mod_ssl use 's' to get value of a variable (working on apache 2.4).
This is an example to set X-Forwarded-For header to REMOTE_ADDR.

```
RequestHeader setifempty x-forwarded-for %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
```

[More info about mod_headers.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)